# Magento URL rewrites creating suffix

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

Magento is creating all of my product urls with a suffix of -xxx three numbers ive checked all the settings in the config and everything seems to be ok, ive attached a screen shot has any one got any ideas how to fix this?[image: screenshot]

Comment: it may be your product id

Answer (score 0):

[EcomDev's Url Indexer](http://shop.ecomdev.org/url-rewrite-indexer.html) solve this problem (works on 1.8, I've just tested it).

If you have an issue when editing products or categories when update on save is on, I've [proposed a fix](https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_UrlRewrite/issues/17#issuecomment-44264693)